# Convert text to a Date with just Month and Year fields on row-level formula on report

Tags: reporting, report-formula

I am trying to convert month (picklist), year (text) to a row-level formula date field and setting the DD as "01", but values for the column are not populating.

Row-level formula:

```
DATEVALUE("Year__c-Converted_Month_Number__c-01")
```

Text formula field to convert month to a two character text value:

```
CASE(Month__c, "January", "01", "February", "02", "March", "03", "April", "04", "May", "05", "June", "06", "July", "07", "August", "08", "September", "09", "October", "10", "November", "11", "December", "12", "00")
```

[image: fx Goal Date not populating]

I am following the Salesforce Help Doc format:
DATEVALUE( "YYYY-MM-DD" )
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=formula_using_date_datetime.htm&type=5

Answer (score 0):

You can use this formula instead:

```
DATE( Year__c, Converted_Month_Number__c, 1 )
```

I think what you have would work if you put it like this:

```
DATEVALUE(TEXT(Year__c) + "-" + TEXT(Converted_Month_Number__c) + "-01")
```

It looks like this when its parsed:

```
DATEVALUE("1990" + "- " + "01" + "-01")
DATEVALUE("1990-01-01")
```

Instead of this, which isn't a date & doesn't reference any fields:

```
DATEVALUE("Year__c-Converted_Month_Number__c-01")
```

Putting a field inside a text string like `"Year__c"` just gives you a string with that text, not the value of the field as a string.

Answer (score 0):

My syntax was incorrect on the row-level formula.

Successful formula:

```
DATEVALUE(Year__c+"-"+Converted_Month_Number__c+"-"+"01")
```